# How can I go about using a **CSS** resource file in one OSGi bundle from another OSGi bundle

Tags: java, css, resources, osgi, bndtools

My project directory structure (in Eclipse):

```
MyProjectContainingCSS/
    src/        --> "source directory" on Eclipse's classpath/buildpath
        com.me.myapp
            style.css


MyProjectInheritingCSS/
    src/        --> "source directory" on Eclipse's classpath/buildpath
        com.me.myapp
            StyleImpl.java
```

I would like to use in the CSS file **style.css** contained in the OSGi bundle `MyProjectContainingCSS` in the other OSGi bundle `MyProjectContainingCSS` in the class `StyleImpl.java`,

Something like:

```
public class StyleImpl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        css = this.getClass().getResource("/com/me/myapp/style.css").toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
    }
}
```

How can I go about using a **CSS** resource file in one OSGi bundle from another OSGi bundle?

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

**The bnd.bnd file**

```
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.${tstamp}
-buildpath: \
    ../cnf/plugins/org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation-3.2.0.jar;version=file,\
    org.apache.felix.dependencymanager,\
    osgi.core,\
    launcher;version=latest,\
    libs/commons-io-2.4.jar;version=file
Private-Package: ui.impl
Export-Package: ui
Import-Package: *
```

**Run Descriptor**

```
-runfw: org.apache.felix.framework;version='[4,5)'
-runee: JavaSE-1.8
-runsystemcapabilities: ${native_capability}

-resolve.effective: active;skip:="osgi.service"
-runbundles: \
    org.apache.felix.dependencymanager,\
    org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.runtime,\
    org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell,\
    org.apache.felix.metatype,\
    org.apache.felix.eventadmin,\
    org.apache.felix.configadmin,\
    org.apache.felix.log,\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.command,\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,\
    launcher;version=latest,\
    ui;version=latest,\
    mainscreen;version=latest
-runsystempackages: javafx.application,javafx.scene,javafx.stage,javafx.scene.layout,javafx.event,javafx.collections,javafx.scene.control,javafx.scene.paint,javafx.scene.shape
```

Comment: Create a class in the CSS bundle to expose the InputStream to CSS file and import this class in another bundle.

Comment: How does one bundle know that a specific resource with a specific name will be found in another bundle? That kind of assumption means you are violating modular encapsulation. Try to find a solution that doesn't make assumptions about other modules. Why not describe the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

To get the file from your own bundle, you can do:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());
Enumeration<URL> resources = bundle.getResources("/com/me/myapp/style.css");   
if (resources != null) {
    URL myCSS = resources.nextElement();
}
```

If you can find the other OSGi bundle object, you can do the same. I would try something like this:

```
    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());
    Bundle[] bArray = bundle.getBundleContext().getBundles();
    Bundle cssBundle = null;
    for (Bundle b : bArray){
        if(b.getSymbolicName().equals("com.me.myapp")) {
            cssBundle = b;
            break; 
        }
    }
    Enumeration<URL> resources = cssBundle.getResources("/com/me/myapp/style.css");   
    if (resources != null) {
        URL myCSS = resources.nextElement();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Marcos Zolnowski  I've put your code in one of my classes called **MainScreen**, but I'm unable to use the method `FrameworkUtil.getBundle`. It gets an error highlight with the warning `The method getBundle(Class<capture#1-of ? extends MainScreen>) is undefined for the type FrameworkUtil`. What could be the problem.

Comment: FrameworkUtil is a class from the org.osgi.framework package. The same package of Bundle. What version of OSGi you use?

Comment: I'm totally new to OSGi. I'm not sure how to check for the OSGi version. I'm using BND tools in eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Comment: No problem, because the system doesn't tell you. Can you tell me the version of `org.osgi.framework` package?

Comment: I just updated the Question with some new info, while I try to find out about the `org.osgi.framework package`

Comment: Some versions of bndtools has issues with generics. But I am not sure now. You could try to cast: `FrameworkUtil.getBundle((Class) myClass)`

Comment: I've moved this issue to [this question : **The method getBundle(Class<capture#1-of ? extends MyClass>) is undefined for the type FrameworkUtil**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389583/the-method-getbundleclasscapture1-of-extends-myclass-is-undefined-for-the). I'll accept your answer shortly. First let me try getting `FrameworkUtil.getBundle` and `bundle.getBundleContext()` to work. Thank you so much for the help so far.

Comment: The only way I can think of loading the CSS onto a JavaFx scene is by passing the URL to an `OutputStream` then creating a *temporary* css file to load onto the scene. Can you think of another simpler way to do this?

Comment: Rather than using static hacks like `FrameworkUtil.getBundle`, it's *much* better to obtain your `BundleContext` by implementing a bundle activator or DS component with an `activate` method.

Comment: A static field holding the context, or something with XML, is not **much** better to me.